# converting a static website to joomla

Tags: html, joomla

I have built a static website for a friend and now he came back asking me to convert it to Joomla, I looked it up online and stumbled on some tutorials, but those tutorials weren't very helpful as they seem to convert home page only.

I've managed to create the home page and converted the main parts to modules .

Now how do I go about inserting the other pages into Joomla?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create the old pages as individual articles and then create a menu item for each page pointing to the coresponding article.

Answer (score 1):

Agree wih Bakual, assuming you are on Joomla 3, just take each of your pages into an aricle.  To start you can just leave them all uncategorized, then later if it makes sense you can move them around into a more complex structure. Of course if you need a contact form etc make that instead.

Have you logged into the administrator? The Absolute Beginner's Guide on http://docs.joomla.org is not bad.  I don't want to self promote but you could also Google "Working with and Creating Content for Your Joomla! Site"